# Preview a disabled CMS Page?

Tags: magento-1.8, cms

How do you preview a cms page on the frontend which is disabled?
I want to add content to a page and before making it live I want to see what it looks like

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a feature in the Enterprise edition. I am also sure that with a quick google you could find a "good" extension that will create this functionality in Magento CE.

What I would suggest maybe doing is to have a local version of your shop which you can test content and code changes on. In this case you can try your changes locally and then migrate them to live later.

You can migrate them to live by a few means.

1. Simply copy and paste them,
2. Create a set-up script that makes the changes you need,
3. Look into a third party tool like [MageFlow](https://mageflow.com/) which is a versioning system for different entities in Magento,